# Bind textbox to selectList Angular

Tags: angularjs, model-binding

Is there any way to bind textbox to select list without `$Watch` .

the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n2KHn25NnVbEvoFxay1P?p=preview)

i don't want to let user type everything and bind to selectlist .

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do ?

Comment: want to bind textbox to selectlist

Comment: So when user insert a value in the input it's add an option on the select list?

Comment: no just user can select the options

Comment: I don't understand why do you need a input if you don't want to make it interact with user and give only the choice to select an option . Just make a single select ...

Answer (score 0):

So if you need to make a select and to display the result in your input without $scope.$watch just use the attribut disabled on the input. Try this :

```
   <input type="text" ng-model="text.name" disabled/>
    <select ng-model="text" ng-options="option.name for option in options">
   </select>
```

In your controller :

```
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = [{
     name: 'a',
     value: 'something-cool-value'
     }, {
      name: 'b',
      value: 'something-else-value'
      }];
```

You can try in your plunker this is working. Hope this helped.

Comment: assume that there are like 100 options in selectlist , and input help user to search via textbox to find specefic option

Comment: @sani, this is called AutoCompleteTextBox. Elementary google search shows http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/

Comment: @sani next time, just make a better explication of your problem my answer is not what you need ...